# Sinatra Content Type both json and form

Tags: json, sinatra

I have been looking all over for how to properly check respond to a application/json type as well as a submitted form. I finally got it working on my own with the following code. Can someone explain why it works? Or offer advice on a better solution to achieve the same thing?

```
post '/login', provides: :json do
p = params
if request.content_type == 'application/json'
  params = JSON.parse(request.body.read, :symbolize_names => true)
else 
  params = p
end


requires(params, :email, :password)

if @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    log_user_in(@user)
    rabl :login, object: @user
  else
    error 404, {error: "incorrect credentials"}.to_json
  end
else
  error 404, {error: "user not found"}.to_json
end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

JSON requests are submitted in the body of the html request so this works but overriding the params hash is not advisable if using RESTful routes.

Hey Curtis.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `::Rack::JSONBodyParser` from [`rack-contrib`](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib):

> A Rack middleware that makes JSON-encoded request bodies available in
> the   request.params hash. By default it parses POST, PATCH, and PUT
> requests whose media type is application/json. You can
> configure it to match any verb or media type via the :verbs
> and :media options.

Examples:

- Parse POST and GET requests only

  `use Rack::JSONBodyParser, verbs: ['POST', 'GET']`
- Parse POST|PATCH|PUT requests whose Content-Type matches 'json'

  `use Rack::JSONBodyParser, media: /json/`
- Parse POST requests whose Content-Type is 'application/json' or 'application/vnd+json'

  `use Rack::JSONBodyParser, verbs: ['POST'], media: ['application/json', 'application/vnd.api+json']`